# How can i install components of android studio?

Tags: android-studio, installation, components

I install Android Studio 3.3.1. But  some components are not install due to weak internet.I want to know the process about install these components without  installation of android studio again .

Comment: Are you talking about the IDE or the SDK? The IDE can technically work without the SDK (although horribly)

Comment: i am talking about SDK.

Comment: In that case, you can open the SDK manager from Android Studio, or launching the standalone manager (unless Google removed that... It's been a while since I've seen that one used)

Comment: got to File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK -> install required sdk and sdk tools